# How to prevent redundancy in Image Data when training a network?

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a large quantity of images of different and random sizes.

I would like to make sure that 
- my training set is not redundant
- the data in my test set are all different (from the others in the test set and from the training set)

By not redundant, I mean basically to check if an image is not a cropped version of another (or the same image at the biggest extend).

How do you deal with such cases in general when working on a net? 
Anything maybe ready for this plugged-in in Tensorflow somehow?

Thank you for the help

K.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4072/how-can-i-find-duplicate-photos is the

Comment: Great!! thanks a lot @ThomasPinetz ! (my google searches didn't output this one ;)) Will check witch one suits me the most.

Comment: While I'm not an ML expert, I have the feeling that it might be counterproductive to do this. First, if the duplicates represent your original distribution, removing them might worsen the result; and secondly, it is common to _add_ randomly cropped and transformed samples when learning from image data sets, to increase number of samples as well as robustness.

Comment: Please note that asking for tool recommendations is off-topic for SO. You may want to consider editing that out of the question.

Comment: @phg it does not represent the original distribution. Additionally, in my specific case,  it is important that my test set will be completely disconnected from any data used in the training.

Answer (score 1):

**What you've to do:**

*Add first image to a set (A) and then parse remaining images one by one and add only those images to (A) which DIFFERS from all images in (A). Keep iterating through to last image. Now use set (A) images for training and testing say 80% of (A) for training rest for testing*

**How To Determine: Redundancy ?**

In simple words *two scaled square images* are same or redundant as both are having *four right angled corners (or features)*. If one square image is cropped then also it will have minimum 2 matching corners (*or matching features*).

Thus in order to determine **redundant images** you need to *find local features* of images then *calculate how many features are matching*.

This can be achieved via **SIFT (scale invariant feature transform)** and other techniques like **SURF local feature detector**. Use [this](https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html) article to get basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like http://geeqie.sourceforge.net/ is doing the trick

Thanks  @ThomasPinetz

K.